# Is it possible to Merge stacks with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, stack

I'm just starting to learn LINQ,
I'm wondering if it would be possible to group the elements in 3 different stacks using LINQ.
this is what I have, could it be possible to add more than one array in the from clause, and how?

```
        var uniqueValues =
            from n in valuesStack.ToArray()
            group n by n into nGroup
            select nGroup.Key;
```

Comment: Are you describing the equivalent of a UNION query in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Union` the stacks together.

```
var s1 = new Stack<int>();
var s2 = new Stack<int>();
var s3 = new Stack<int>();
var r = s1.Union(s2.Union(s3)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect for what I need! I'll keep trying the LINQ option just to know it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var uniqueValues = stack1
    .Concat(stack2)
    .Concat(stack3)
    .Distinct();
```

or you could use Union:

```
var uniqueValues = stack1
    .Union(stack2)
    .Union(stack3);
```

Comment: perfect :) So I get that the use of LINQ is not necessary for this, but could it be done?

Comment: @david: `Union` is considered a LINQ operator. It is part of the `Enumerable` class in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: @Robery: sort-of a grey area. "LINQ" is "Language Integrated Query", but this is not using any language query features, just the library.

Comment: @James - Actually I would consider this black-and-white. Unless you write a query such as `from s in sl select s` you are not using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested:

```
var uniqueValues =
    from stack in stacks
    from n in stack
    group n by n into nGroup
    select nGroup.Key;
```